# Ajax: do something with the result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I use jQuery Ajax. I send the id to another page, there I make a select of a MySql database: with the id I select a colum and I echo a row. This works well. But the function second does not work, the question is: how can I click to the div with the class bookmark that comes from the other page (proces.php) with ajax?

index.php:

```
<div id="button">button</div>
<div id="solution"></div>
```

index.php (after the ajax call):

```
<div id="button">button</div>
<div id="solution">
    <div class="bookmark"> 13.13 </div>
</div>
```

jQuery-Ajax:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    $.post("proces.php", 
    { id: 299 }
    ,function (result) { $("#solution").html(result); }
    ); 
});

function second(){   
    $(".bookmark").click(function(){
        alert('it works!');
    });
}
```

proces.php:

```
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM bookmarks
                              WHERE id = '$id' ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $minut = $row["minut"];     
?>
<div class="bookmark"> <?php echo $minut; ?> </div>
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an active listener, instead of a javascript function `second`. There are 2 issue here:

1. You have a javascript function, that never gets called on click
2. Since the elements are rendered dynamically, `.click()` would *not* work because the DOM would not have attached an active listener to a dynamically generated html element.

So, change

```
function second(){   
    $(".bookmark").click(function(){
        alert('it works!');
    });
}
```

to

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on("click", ".bookmark", function(){
        alert('it works! - ' + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

This is called [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) where you are attaching the listener to the parent node (`document` in this case), and firing the listener on its descendant (`.bookmark`) , which otherwise would not work for dynamically rendered html elements on the document.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call `second()` within the success callback of your `$.post`.

```
$.post("proces.php", { id: 299 } ,function (result) { 
    $("#solution").html(result); 
    second();
});
```

Beware however that if other elements with the same class already exist that the handlers for those elements will be bound again.

For simple event handlers the more common approach nowadays is using event delegation.
However for more complex situations like initializing plugins this is how you would need to handle them